# Can I enhance complex table accessibility with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

A website has a great number of complex informational [tables with multi-level headers](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/multi-level/), a simple version of which is:

```css
table { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; width: 100%; }
td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
th { background-color: lightgray; }
```

```html
<!-- simplified table -->
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th></th><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Row 1</th><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th colspan="3">Header for subregion</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Row 2</th><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Row 3</th><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For various reasons, server-side and hand-coded solutions are out. If I use JavaScript that applies the suggested WAI fixes (["use id and headers attributes to associate header and data cells explicitly"](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/)) to enhance the HTML, will this be reliably reflected in what users actually get in a screen reader?

Using [ARIA Live Regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) seems like it would needlessly update them to a host of changes. So, ideally, can it work without that?

Comment: One thing you should keep in mind is that somewhere around 2% of screen reader users will have JavaScript disabled. Even though this number sounds small, it can turn into hundreds if not thousands of people very quickly, depending on the traffic of your website. You may want to consider planning on having some method for falling back gracefully if the JavaScript fails or is blocked.

Comment: @Josh, the best/worst part is they'll be no worse off than the plain table if JS fails to load. Thanks for the headsup, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "yes".  In general(*), any attributes you apply via javascript, whether ARIA attributes or any other html attributes, will be available to screen readers.

(*) There is (at least) one exception that I'm aware of, [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live).  There are browser and screen reader combinations where that attribute has to exist on the element when the page is loaded in order for it to be honored.  You mentioned `aria-live` in your question but that attribute doesn't really come into play unless you are making updates to your page dyanamically (for example, if you table headers changed based on some user action).

I was going to show some sample code to show the desired results based on your code snippet, but your example is a little confusing.  You have a "Header for subregion" that spans all the columns.  Visually, it looks more like a caption/summary for the table than it does a column header.  Can you clarify?  Table captions should **not** be coded as headers (<strike><th></strike>).

Do you want "Header for subregion" to be read as the column header for every cell?

Comment: It's a header for everything that comes under it. The column headers still apply, and any row headers. So I believe if it had an id of 'sub1' , then headers for the row would be 'sub1 col1 row5' and so on? See example 2 at https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/multi-level/#table-with-three-headers-related-to-each-data-cell That's the kind of table it is.

Comment: Yes, example 2 is very similar to yours.  You definitely have to use the `id` and `headers` attributes rather than simply relying on `<th scope="col">` or `<th scope="row">`.  So you want **both** "col 1" and "Header for subregion" to be column headers for the cell "foo".

Comment: Thanks again! I'm still getting oriented in accessibility. Marking as the answer--do you have any resource (I could find nothing specific) saying, or test showing, that this is the case?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question.  A resource showing "what" is the case?  That you need to use id/headers instead of relying on `<th>`?  If so, that would be the W3 tutorial page that you listed earlier.  Using `<th>` with the `scope` attribute is for "regular" tables.  Your table is not quite regular.  If your "header for subregion" had `<th scope="col" colspan="3">`, then some screen readers might try to use it as a column header for "row 1".  If you use id/headers, then you are specifically telling each cell what to use as the headers.

Comment: No, that I get. I'm referring to the main question: that JS is a (relatively) safe way to provide this info (that screen readers will get them).

Comment: Absolutely it is.  ARIA attributes are broken down into two categories: states and properties.  Properties are typically set once and don't change, such as `aria-live` or `aria-multiline`.  States are expected to change, such as `aria-expanded` or `aria-pressed`, and usually do so based on user interaction.  The way the states are changed is via javascript.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#dfn-state and https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#statevsprop